# How to handle missing tasks due to non-deterministic failures in a micro service using gRPC?

Tags: architecture, event-handling, microservices, grpc

Suppose I have two micro services, <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd>, where <kbd>A</kbd> makes a gRPC call to <kbd>B</kbd> with some data, and <kbd>B</kbd> performs a long running task and publishes an event with the result on completion that <kbd>A</kbd> and other services consume.

[image]
[image]

If <kbd>B</kbd> is up when the call is made but, for some non-deterministic reason, crashes while processing the data and has to be respawned, **how can <kbd>A</kbd> still get its result?**
In something like Kafka this isn't a problem as messages are kept until they are deleted/the timeout passes, but without a message queue I can't really see any way for either <kbd>A</kbd> to trigger the process again, or for <kbd>B</kbd> to keep track of events it hasn't processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can either switch communication pattern between `A` and `B` to be asynchronous one via some message broker (or introduce `AB` service which will handle request from `A` and turn them into incoming messages for `B`) or just save the incoming data to some persistent store (i.e. database/disk) before starting the long running processing and use this to track the status of events.

Comment: For making B persistent, it might be useful to have B be event-sourced and publish intermediate events as it makes progress.  On restart, B would scan through the events published by earlier incarnations of B and recover its state from those, thus avoiding a situation where B's internal state doesn't match what it's published.